# getting the cursor of the user input to be on the same line as the printed statement

Tags: python-3.x, input

I have a program which I would like the user to input the answer on the same line as the question which is printed.

the code looks like this:

```
question = 1
number1 = 2
number2 = 2

print(question , ") " , "What is" , number1 , "+" , number2 , "? ")

user_ans = int(input("")) #The Answer the user inputs to the question asked

print (user_ans)
```

But the Output is:

```
1) What is (number1) + (number2) ?
(the cursor goes here)
```

However how do I get the output to be this:

```
1) What is (number1) + (number2) ? (the cursor goes here)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, by default the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function has the keyword argument `end=\n`, so a newline is created every time you call it.

To prevent this behavior, simply specify the `end` keyword  argument yourself with `end=''` to ensure no newline character is placed at the end of your output string

```
print(question , ") " , "What is" , number1 , "+" , number2 , "? ", end='')
```

As an aside, I would consider using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to make your output strings easier to look at.

```
print(str.format('{0}. What is {1} + {2}?', question, number1, number2), end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

> input(question , ") " , "What is" , number1 , "+" , number2 , "? ")

or even better

> input('{}) What is {} + {}? '.format(question, number1,number2))

This would result in the prompt waiting on the same line.
I would even suggest using fixed widths in the formatters so the prompt would always be in the same column.
This could be written like so:

> '{:2}) What is {:^3}+{:^3}?'.format(question, number1,number2)

This would look like this:

`In [81]: '{:2}) What is {:^3}+{:^3}?'.format(question,number1,number2) 
Out[81]: '1 ) What is  2 + 3 ?'
Out[84]: '11) What is 45 +21 ?'`

The `{:^3}` means in this case 'center the content adhering 3 spacings'. See [here](https://pyformat.info/) for more clarification (look for the topic 'Padding and aligning strings')
For example, you might rather want a left alignment, use `{:<3}` instead